# UISearchBar stretches text when it begins editing

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uisearchbar

I have an instance of a UISearchBar added to the title view of a UINavigationBar. When there is text already set and the search bar starts editing it resizes its contents to allow space for the Cancel button, although, the resulting animation stretches the text, as showed in the gif below

[image]

Is there anything that can be done to avoid this <strike>defect</strike> effect? I have tried to remove the text and then to add it back a few moments later, although it works, it is not an elegant solution.

**Update**

---

Based on @Paruru's answer I tried to anticipate the animation of the `Cancel` button and it doesn't look bad. What I did is that I force the presentation of the `Cancel` button on `searchBarShouldBeginEditing:`

```
extension SearchViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
        if searchBar.text?.isEmpty == false {
            // This avoids the text being stretched by the UISearchBar.
            searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

The end result is what I want to achieve, the animation without the text being stretched. I consider this to be a workaround, and so I'll wait for other answers as this code might not be future proof.

Comment: Your updated solution works great, you should post it as an answer so I can upvote it!

Comment: HI Alex, I don't want to make it the correct answer as it is a hack and might be damaging for newer versions of the iOS, that could have a fix the animation issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your updated solution works well, except it stops the "Search" placeholder from being animated to the left when the Cancel button appears while there is no text. Checking `searchBar.text` restores the animation:

```
func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
    // This avoids the text being stretched by the UISearchBar.
    if searchBar.text?.isEmpty == false {
        searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
    }
    return true
}
```

I suspect this may only be an issue for the `Minimal` `UISearchBarStyle`.

Comment: Thanks Alex! I'll update the question, adding your suggestion.

Comment: Instead of `searchBar.text?.isEmpty == false` use `!searchBar.text?.isEmpty`

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)setShowsCancelButton:(BOOL)showsCancelButton animated:(BOOL)animated NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);
```

Just call the method without animated.

```
if (!self.isShowCancelBtn) {
    [self.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:NO];
    self.isShowCancelBtn = YES;
}else{
    [self.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:NO];
    self.isShowCancelBtn = NO;
}
```

Comment: That will make the button jump in and out of the search bar, and that's not what I'd like to achieve. I mentioned above that I found a work around. What I'm looking for is a solution not another bandaid solution