# UISearchController "manual" search UI glitch

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uisearchcontroller

We're migrating from `UISearchDisplayController` to `UISearchController`, one feature that used to work perfectly is misbehaving a bit and I'm wondering if we're not using the API as intended.

We have a `UITableViewController` that uses a `UISearchController` and a separate results controller to display the results, on some cases when the user clicks on a cell in the original table we want to invoke the `UISearchController` and populate the search field with a predefined text.

There's some kind of a UI glitch that we didn't have originally when we used `UISearchDisplayController`

The code we used to manually invoke the search controller is:

```
[self.providerSearchResultsController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
[self.providerSearchResultsController.searchBar setText:providerName];
```

I couldn't find anything official in Apple documentation.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this question will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31846311/uisearchbar-stretches-text-when-it-begins-editing

Answer (score 0):

i believe that following link might help you 
https://github.com/rnystrom/UITableViewController-Containment-Demo

Comment: From glimpsing at the code it uses the deprecated `UISearchDisplayController`, like I wrote in the original question it worked when we used that class